# Removing appended 'n' from BigInt()

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bigint

I am trying to use BigInt() to compute the factorial of number greater than 20.

Below is my function to compute the factorial:

```
function extraLongFactorials(n) {
// let result=BigInt(1);
// console.log(typeof(result));
let result=BigInt(1);
for(let i=n;i>1;i--){
result*=BigInt(i);
}
// console.log(typeof(result));
// console.log(result);
// BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.toString()  }
// result=JSON.stringify(result)
console.log(result);

}
```

I am getting the result, however in the end n is being appendes, so the result is something like 15511210043330985984000000n, whereas I am expected to show a result 15511210043330985984000000.
Is there a way to remove the n from the end ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt/toString):

```
console.log(result.toString());
// or
console.log(String(result));
// or
console.log('' + result);
```

Comment: If it is not too much trouble to ask, could you explain what exactly happened ? I mean to ask is that if it is converted to string, how is it different from          BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.toString()  }
 result=JSON.stringify(result);

Comment: Yeah it does, but in the answer it has "." which was not for toString().